# Graph: absolute vertex size

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

How can I set absolute vertex sizes in `Graph`, so that the vertex size on screen (number of pixels or printer's points) is invariant to changes in the option `ImageSize`? All of the types of setting in the documentation for `VertexSize` cause the on-screen size to change with `ImageSize`.

This is useful for example to match vertex sizes between multiple `Graph`s used in different panels of the same publication figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that it is possible to do this with `VertexSize`. The vertex sizes used by `Graph` are translated to plot coordinates, not to absolute coordinates.

A practical solution is to set a [`VertexShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexShapeFunction.html) that will ignore the sizes passed to it and renders at a constant *absolute* size.

```
SeedRandom[42]
g = RandomGraph[{30, 60}]
```

```
g = Graph[g, 
       VertexShapeFunction -> Function[{pt, v, size}, Disk[pt, Offset[5]]]];
```

```
Table[Show[g, ImageSize -> size], {size, {100, 200, 300}}]
```

[image]

The vertices are always rendered as disks having a radius of 5 pixels, regardless of the image size. You might want to add `ImagePadding -> 5` to the above to make sure that there is always enough margin left to render these disks.

If the graph is directed, it is important to add

```
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
```

so that arrowheads will be positioned correctly.

---

Unfortunately, the technique above will often lead to parts of the vertices being cut off at the image borders. The [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) must be increased manually to prevent this.

When a simple disc, without outlines, is sufficient, it is more convenient to use `Point` with `AbsolutePointSize`:

```
VertexShapeFunction -> ({AbsolutePointSize[15], Point[#1]} &)
```

This avoids the vertices being cropped.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to use a shape other than `Disk`? I see in the documentation that `Inset` will do the trick, but would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: @CarbonFlambe It does not matter what the shape it. As I said, all you need to do is write your own VertexShapeFunction that ignores the size argument and produces something in absolute coordinates (see `Offset`)

Comment: @CarbonFlambe--ReinstateMonica I updated the answer with some extra information. Actually, `Inset` might be the simplest way to handle arbitrary shapes ...